# python - reading txt file and checking if the file is empty

Tags: python

I have a file that is empty at the moment called `Savings.txt`
I want this program to read the file and if the file is empty, call the `user_balance` function.
If its not empty, then call the menu function.

this is what I have:

```py
check = []    
with open('Savings.txt', 'r') as f: 
    pre_check = f.readlines()
    check = pre_check
    if not check:
        user_balance()
    else:
        menu()
```

When I run this, even though the file is empty, it goes to the menu function.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if your file has whitespaces, it'll go to the menu() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your so called empty file most likely has one single new line inside. So `.readlines` actually returns `['\n']` - which is indeed a truthy value.

If "empty", by your definition, means any file that has no contents **ignoring whitespace** - read the file and `.strip` its contents before performing the check

```py
with open('Savings.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().strip()
    # Check if content is truthy/falsy
```

[`.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will get rid of any leading or trailing whitespace (including newlines)